# AIX: process name in core naming

Tags: aix

We can use chcore on AIX to set the default core naming pattern on|off which would be.

```
  core.<pid>.<timestamps>
```

Is there a way to change this default pattern ? 
I'm interested in prefixing crashed process name as well in the pattern. like we can do it on Linux with %e.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant commands in AIX.

There is the [`syscorepath`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds5%2Fsyscorepath.htm) command, and, as you mentioned, `chcore`, which makes the setting persist across reboots.

Neither of them allows you to specify that process name should be part of the name of the core file.